# After switching to an external SSD drive for macOS, can I still use my internal Fusion HDD drive and will Time Machine see both drives?

Tags: macos, ssd, time-machine

I’ve upgraded my Mac’s storage from a Fusion drive to an SSD and my plan is to run macOS and all Apps from the SSD and store data and pictures on the internal Fusion Drive.

So my questions are:

1. Should I reformat the Fusion HDD then move the data and pic files back from the SSD?
2. Will Time Machine see both drives and back them up automatically?

System details:

- 2017 27”iMac Expanded Ram to 40GB.
- MacOS Monterey 12.5.
- 1TB Fusion Drive.
- WD Elements External HDD 1TB with Time Machine.

External SSH drive for macOS:

- TEKQ Super Veloce Thunderbolt external NVMe SSD enclosure with a PNY CS2140 1TB NVMe drive inside.

Comment: Your [original question](https://superuser.com/posts/1735565/revisions) was not a question but a long, overly detailed essay. I have edited it to it‘s core issue and details and provided a real question for the title. That said, this is pretty much an opinion-based question. In my mind you can do both things without issue. The Fusion drive is just storage; might work well but if it was slow before it might still be slow now. Also Time Machine will gladly back up any and all storage on the system; in fact you would need to go out of your way to get Time Machine to ignore storage.

Comment: PS: That said, I missed this part initially, “…my plan is to run macOS and all Apps from the SSD and store data and pictures on the internal Fusion Drive.” Technically this can be done. As long as the external SSD has a decent connection to the Mac, this should be fine. But as a permanent solution? I don’t like it. External drives can be knocked loose and such so that is a risk. And honestly an internal drive would be inherently more stable and faster. But if you have no choice I would try it out and see how it feels. It can’t damage anything!

Comment: Many thanks for your response - I guess it was a little convoluted .

Comment: Running MacOS from an external SSD is a well documented process to deal with the poor performance of Fusion Drive. Using Thunderbolt connection gives me great read/write speed. So my original question really is should I reformat my Fusion Drive and reinstall my data and pics files or just delete the apps and OS. Is formatting a fusion Drive the same as a normal HDD - Thanks again

Comment: “Is formatting a fusion Drive the same as a normal HDD.” Yes! Formatting a Fusion drive is no different than formatting a hard drive, SSD drive or a USB flash drive. It is just storage. It all looks like formatted storage to the system. That’s it.

Answer (score 0):

I have an iMac that uses an external OWC Envoy Pro FX Thunderbolt external drive as the boot drive.  It's about 3 times faster than the original  Fusion internal drive.

The other options are:

1. Install an SSD internally, replacing the Fusion SATA drive.  But SATA is a bottleneck and it will be slower than the external Thunderbolt drive.  And accessing the innards of the iMac involves removing the screen.  It's a delicate operation that can lead to a cracked screen if you're not careful.
2. The factory Fusion Drive is a combination of a SATA drive and a small  NVMe SSD cache drive that is plugged into a PCIe slot on the backside of the Apple main board.

The PCIe bus is much faster than SATA or Thunderbolt and is the fastest option for replacing the Fusion Drive.  The process involves "breaking" or separating the Fusion Drive's SATA HDD from the NVMe cache drive using a Terminal command.  Once the SATA drive and the NVMe are unjoined from one another, you can replace the NVMe drive with a much larger one.  They have gotten pretty affordable and they're screaming fast!

The downside of this fastest option is that you have to dive deep into disassembling the iMac.  It involves removing many internal connections, the power supply, the fan enclosures, the SATA drive, etc.  This option concerns me that I might destroy my iMac performing this open heart surgery.

OWC has a video and an optional kit to remove the screen, and replace the PCIe connected NVMe drive.  If you're adventurous and competent, this is the fastest upgrade option.  Check out [their site](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/imac-27-inch/2013-2019) and [their PCI SSD installation video](https://eshop.macsales.com/installvideos/imac-27-inch-5k-2019-pciessd/).

But your original question remains:  What to do with the legacy SATA drive after all this?  I kept mine and left it alone.  If my external Envoy drive fails, I might use the internal drive as an optional boot drive to perform maintenance.  But mostly, I don't use it anymore at all.  I don't need the optional, slower storage.

If I ever decide to bite the bullet and break into the iMac chassis and add the PCI connected NVMe SSD, I'll likely remove the SATA drive altogether to save on the energy required to spin that unused drive.